# Play Framework: Netty fails to bind after recompile

Tags: java, scala, playframework, akka

I am working on a project in the Play Framework using Akka and Memcached . When I change the java source in the IDE, play automatically re compiles and reruns/reloads. There is code in our project that looks for a free port for Akka. It starts at 40000. Tries to open and close a socket on the port. On success, it constructs a configuration for Akka including found available ports. But later this initialization fails throwing this exception:

```
 Caused by: org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /127.0.0.1:40000

 at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272)
 at akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$listen$1.apply(NettyTransport.scala:377)
 at akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$listen$1.apply(NettyTransport.scala:374)
 at scala.util.Success$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Try.scala:206)
 at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
 at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:206)
 at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)
 at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)
 at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
 at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:67)
 at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:82)
 at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59)
 at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59)
 at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
 at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:58)
 at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:42)
 at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
 at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
 at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
 at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
 at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

 Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use

 at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:344)
 at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:336)
 at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:199)
 at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
 at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss$RegisterTask.run(NioServerBoss.java:193)
 at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.processTaskQueue(AbstractNioSelector.java:366)
 at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:290)
 at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss.run(NioServerBoss.java:42)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Strange thing is that this code works on Ubuntu, but does not on Mac OSX (Maverics). Any idea would be most appreciated.

Comment: Through what mechanism are you expecting the existing instance to release its port?

Comment: Try using `sudo lsof -i4` in the Terminal to find out if someone is taking over the offending port. It looks like your old instance is still running so it's still holding the port.

Comment: I am not an architect of this project. I would like to dig into it, but I do not have time for it. But what is certain, this works properly on ubuntu. It fails only on OSX. Moreover I debuged the initialization code and before AKKA/NETTY starts, this port is free. Problem occurs clearly during startup of AKKA or Netty.